# how to generate md5 + salt password for salted-hash spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-security, md5, salt

I'm working on migrating legacy system to java web application. now i'm using spring mvc + spring security + spring boot jpa with no xml. But i got problem when log in as spring security 4 using bcyrpt. legacy db password generated using md5 + salted.

Answer (score 0):

You need configuration similar to this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    Md5PasswordEncoder md5CryptEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService myDetailsService

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(md5CryptEncoder);
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(myDetailsService);
            ReflectionSaltSource saltSource = new ReflectionSaltSource();
            saltSource.setUserPropertyToUse("salt");
            authProvider.setSaltSource(saltSource);
            auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

But you have to configure Auth with correct encoder.

Comment: this is my encoder but how about adding salt?                                     @Bean
 public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
  Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
  return md5PasswordEncoder;
 }

Comment: check this article [Spring MD5 Salt](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.sk/2015/02/spring-security-basic-auth-md5password.html)